# Alternating Sub-sequence SPOJ Python (ALTSEQ)

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, lis

This is the 1st time I am trying coding practices on platform like SPOJ. I have used bottom-up approach of dynamic programming and I am submitting below solution for finding maximum length of alternating sub-sequence of +ve and -ve numbers. It is variation of program longest increasing sub-sequence of array.It shows Time Limit Exceeded. Can someone please tell me how can I optimize the below program further?
P.S. This solution is successfully submitted on hackerEarth platform

```
def alternatingSeq(arr,n):
    if(n==1):
        return 1

    dp = [1 for i in range(n)]

    res = 0
    for i in range(1,n):

        for j in range(i):
            if( ((arr[i]<0 and arr[j] > 0 and -arr[i] > arr[j])
            or (arr[i]>0 and arr[j] < 0 and arr[i] > -arr[j])) 
            and dp[i] < 1 + dp[j]):
                dp[i] = 1 + dp[j]


        if(dp[i] > res):
            res = dp[i]

    return res

n = int(input())
arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(alternatingSeq(arr,n))
```

Comment: What's the program supposed to do?

Comment: @AKX I edited the question. let me know if it is still unclear. Thanks